How to comply with Apache 2.0 license?
I am working on a software product that uses a third party component "log4net" for logging. Log4net is licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0
https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net.
I am trying to make sure that I am in compliance with the license.
According to https://www.apache.org/legal/apply-license.html you must include a copy of the license text AND a notice file in the top directory of your distribution.
However the following link says: "Include a copy of the Apache License, typically in a file called LICENSE, in your work, and consider also including a NOTICE file that references the License." This makes the addition of the NOTICE file sound optional.
https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#apply
These links sound contradictory to me.
Ultimately I have the following questions about this:

Is a LICENSE file always required for a component that uses Apache 2.0, such as log4net?

Is a NOTICE file always required?



Let's assume here that you are merely using log4net as a library for logging and you did not modify it or create a derivative work of it.
The Apache License v2.0 states:

For the purposes of this License, Derivative Works shall not include
works that remain separable from, or merely link (or bind by name) to
the interfaces of, the Work and Derivative Works thereof.

So based on the assumption above, there are no Derivative Works in this scenario.
Hence, subsections b, c and d of section 4 of the license is then not applicable to this scenario. You can ignore the NOTICE file since no Derivative Work was created.
Only 4(a) is applicable:

You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative
Works thereof in any medium, with or without modifications, and in
Source or Object form, provided that You meet the following
conditions:
(a) You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works
a copy of this License;

You just have to state somewhere, let's say in a file listing out third party open source software distributed together with your software, that you're distributing log4net unmodified together with your software, and provide a copy of this license, or at least the URL of the license file of log4net.
Sometimes you notice that in Android apps, they have a small link somewhere in a settings area called "Third party open source software licenses". When you tap on it, you can see a long list of the names of software, URLs, maybe their copyright statements if available, and their license texts. You can do it in that way too.
LICENSE or COPYING file is needed to explicitly state the license, only if your software is an open source software.
The initial creation of a NOTICE file is not mandatory according to the language of section 4(d) of the Apache License v2.0.

Do you mean "did not modify" in that first sentence?

@MadHatter Yes. Updated. Thank you.

The link at https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#apply is for applying the Apache license to your work i.e. something where you are the copyright holder. You are not the copyright holder of log4net so what's written there isn't relevant to your situation.
As always, I suggest reading the actual license; the Apache license is somewhat wordy but not that hard to understand. In particular, clause 4(d) is very clear:

If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained within such NOTICE file [...] in at least one of the following places: within a NOTICE text file distributed as part of the Derivative Works; within the Source form or documentation, if provided along with the Derivative Works; or, within a display generated by the Derivative Works, if and wherever such third-party notices normally appear.

i.e. you do not necessarily have to include a NOTICE file, but if you don't you must do one of the other options listed in that clause.
